# Slice a UIImageView into a custom shape

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview

I have a UIImageView that contains an image of a circle.  I would like to be able to remove a portion of the image (while maintaining the transparency) to create the effect of a slice missing as shown below.  My ultimate goal is to create something like the ITunes app, where as you play a song preview, the circle slowly fills in, in a clockwise direction.

[image: Pie Shape]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't need the image of the circle for anything other than the progress display, you could skip the `UIImageView` and just use CoreGraphics to draw the progress indicator.  The basic steps would be:

1. Create a path - `CGContextBeginPath`
2. Add an arc using `CGContextAddArc`
3. Fill the path using `CGContextFillPath`
4. Close the path - `CGContextClosePath`

Repeat this for each progress step, changing the endpoint of your arc each time.

Answer (score 2):

I've implemented a similar filling-up circle with the following code:
(the delegate provides a value between 0 and 1)

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
CGFloat endAngle=([self.delegate giveCompletion]+0.75)*2*M_PI;

UIBezierPath *path=[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:self.center radius:self.bounds.size.width/(3) startAngle:0.75*2*M_PI endAngle:endAngle clockwise:YES];
[path addLineToPoint:self.center];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(self.center.x, self.center.y+self.bounds.size.width/(3)) ];
[path addClip];
[[UIColor blueColor]setFill];
UIRectFill(self.bounds);
}
```

I haven't figured out how to dynamically make it fill up yet, though I guess that this would depend heavily on the specific context where it is being used. Hope it is of any help! Cheers.

Comment: Awesome this code works great!  BTW [self setNeedsDisplay] will cause the view to redraw.